# How to calculate average for individual array items of a column on PySpark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the Pokemon index. I am trying to calculate the average spawn chance for each type of Pokemon. Like Grass, Poison, Fire etc.

```
+---+----------+----------------+------------+
|num|      name|            type|spawn_chance|
+---+----------+----------------+------------+
|001| Bulbasaur| [Grass, Poison]|        0.69|
|002|   Ivysaur| [Grass, Poison]|       0.042|
|003|  Venusaur| [Grass, Poison]|       0.017|
|004|Charmander|          [Fire]|       0.253|
|005|Charmeleon|          [Fire]|       0.012|
|006| Charizard|  [Fire, Flying]|      0.0031|
|007|  Squirtle|         [Water]|        0.58|
|008| Wartortle|         [Water]|       0.034|
|009| Blastoise|         [Water]|      0.0067|
|010|  Caterpie|           [Bug]|       3.032|
|011|   Metapod|           [Bug]|       0.187|
|012|Butterfree|   [Bug, Flying]|       0.022|
|013|    Weedle|   [Bug, Poison]|        7.12|
|014|    Kakuna|   [Bug, Poison]|        0.44|
|015|  Beedrill|   [Bug, Poison]|       0.051|
|016|    Pidgey|[Normal, Flying]|       15.98|
|017| Pidgeotto|[Normal, Flying]|        1.02|
|018|   Pidgeot|[Normal, Flying]|        0.13|
|019|   Rattata|        [Normal]|       13.05|
|020|  Raticate|        [Normal]|        0.41|
+---+----------+----------------+------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

I tried

```
df.select('type','spawn_chance').groupby('type').avg().show()
```

and got.

```
+------------------+--------------------+
|              type|   avg(spawn_chance)|
+------------------+--------------------+
|  [Grass, Psychic]|               0.397|
|           [Water]|  1.0398722222222223|
|          [Poison]|             0.54741|
|      [Water, Ice]|0.011333333333333332|
|   [Water, Poison]|               0.446|
|[Electric, Flying]|                 0.0|
|    [Fire, Flying]|             0.00155|
|   [Ghost, Poison]| 0.28290000000000004|
|         [Psychic]|            0.470925|
|    [Rock, Flying]|               0.018|
|      [Bug, Grass]|  1.2169999999999999|
|    [Rock, Ground]|            0.341425|
|  [Normal, Flying]|  2.8463999999999996|
|          [Dragon]|                0.16|
|  [Dragon, Flying]|              0.0011|
|     [Bug, Flying]|               0.081|
|  [Poison, Ground]|              0.0145|
|   [Water, Flying]|              0.0032|
|    [Ice, Psychic]|                0.35|
|   [Grass, Poison]|  0.3411777777777778|
+------------------+--------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

I am unable to extract the individual types. Any insight is appreciated. The PySpark documentation has very limited info on grouping.

Comment: Depending on how you want to calculate this average you could first explode the type column group by that and then take the average

Answer (score 2):

Does that code solve your problem? I've only taken a subset of sample data, but it should be enough to grasp the concept.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([("001", "Bulbasaur", ["Grass", "Poison"], 0.69), ("002", "Ivysaur", ["Grass", "Poison"], 0.042), ("013", "Weedle", ["Bug", "Poison"], 7.12)], "num: string, name: string, type: array<string>, spawn_chance: double")
df.show()

+---+---------+---------------+------------+
|num|     name|           type|spawn_chance|
+---+---------+---------------+------------+
|001|Bulbasaur|[Grass, Poison]|        0.69|
|002|  Ivysaur|[Grass, Poison]|       0.042|
|013|   Weedle|  [Bug, Poison]|        7.12|
+---+---------+---------------+------------+

df.select("*", explode("type").alias("type_exploded")).groupBy("type_exploded").avg("spawn_chance").show()

+-------------+------------------+
|type_exploded| avg(spawn_chance)|
+-------------+------------------+
|       Poison|2.6173333333333333|
|        Grass|             0.366|
|          Bug|              7.12|
+-------------+------------------+
```